# Difference between rundeck.audit.events.log and rundeck.audit.log

Tags: rundeck

I updated my rundeck version from 3.4.9 to 4.7.0 in my RHEL8 machine and due to that a new log file has been introduced in the application i.e. "rundeck.audit.events.log". I am trying to figure out what does this file contain that "rundeck.audit.log" does not. So basically, what is the difference between both the log files? Does the new log file contain anything different that other log files don't?

I looked at few [articles](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/audit-trail.html#interpreting-the-log-file) explaining rundeck.audit.events.log file but it doesn't contain any difference between both the log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rundeck.audit.log:` Authorization messages pertaining to *aclpolicy* (more info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/document-format-reference/aclpolicy-v10.html#aclpolicy)).

`rundeck.audit.events.log:` Logs all auditing events (users logins, logouts, etc..)

More info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/logs.html#logs).